# mysqli_free_result proper use

Tags: php, mysqli

Had no idea how to summarise this in the title so just put what I put.

I have ran into this problem:

```
$result = $connect->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Then, further down the same script I use the 'result' variable name for something else (an update query, so no MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT):

```
$result = $connect->query($query);
```

And at the end of my script I put:

```
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

I get an error - there is no stored result to free as $result has been set to something else.

My question is....

When I executed the first query:

```
$result = $connect->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Would the result continue to be stored even after making $result equal to something else?

Or, would the result be freed when assigning $result the second query execution?

Answer (score 1):

First do following

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* Update table doesn't return a resultset */
if (mysqli_query($link, "Update tb1 Set col1="qqq"") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table tb1 successfully updated.\n");
}

// Select queries return a resultset

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tb1")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```